Why $(x^{\sin x})' \neq \sin x\cdot x^{\sin x - 1}$
Here is a question in my textbook:

$f(x)=x^{\sin x}(x>0)$, $f'(x)=?$

The answer in the book said:

$$f(x)=x^{\sin x}=e^{\sin x\cdot \ln x}$$
$$f'(x) = e^{\sin x\cdot \ln x}(\sin x\cdot \ln x)' = x^{\sin x}(\cos x \cdot \ln x + \frac{\sin x}{x})$$

But $(x^a)' = ax^{a-1}$, why
$$(x^{\sin x})' \neq \sin x\cdot x^{\sin x - 1}$$

Because in the formula with $a$, $a$ do not depends on $x$. But $\sin(x)$ surely does.

"Power Rule" treating exponent as constant: $\left(x^{\sin x}\right)'=\sin(x)x^{\sin x-1}$ is false.$$ $$
"Exponential Rule" treating base as constant: $\left(x^{\sin x}\right)'=x^{\sin x}\ln(x)\cos(x)$ is false.$$ $$
Add them together: $\left(x^{\sin x}\right)'=\sin(x)x^{\sin x-1} + x^{\sin x}\ln(x)\cos(x)$ is true. This is an instance of the multivariate chain rule in action.

@2'59'2 That is to say $(f(x)^{g(x)})' = g(x)f(x)^{g(x)-1} + f(x)^{g(x)}(\ln f(x))g'(x)$? I don't quite understand how this relates to the chain rule.

@JinLianjun Suppose $u$ and $v$ depend on $x$. Then $\frac{d}{dx}(u^v)=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}u^v\cdot\frac{du}{dx}+\frac{\partial}{\partial v}u^v\cdot\frac{dv}{dx}$. That's one form of the multivariate chain rule.

The formula you provided is called the power rule and it states,
Let $f(x)$ be a function satisfying $f(x)= x^r$, where $r\in \mathbb{R}$ ($r$ is a real number). Then, $f'(x)=rx^{r-1}$
Thus $r$ has to be a real number and not a function as in your case. Since $sin(x)$ is a function and not a real number the rule doesn't apply.
For solving problems like these you need the chain-rule. Defined as follows:
if $h(x) = f(g(x))$ for all x, then,
$h'(x)=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$
I would recommend rereading the chapter to get at solid grasp on the different rules for taking derivatives, and when they are applicable.
Hope this helps.

But for $x^{\sin x}$, it's not appropriate to use chain-rule, right?

Indeed it is applicable. As you can see in the model answer we first transform function to the form. $h(x)=e^{ln(x) \cdot sin(x)}$. Compare to the chain-rule definition I provided above. $g(x) = ln(x) \cdot sin(x)$ becomes the inner function, and the function $f(x)=e^x$ becomes the outer one.
